# Bat file is not running untill any key pressed from keyboard

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, windows-console

My computer has a different problem.

Whatever the batch file i run, it won't starts its execution until i press any key from keyboard until that it holds the data without printing on console/command prompt.

once i press a key the execution starts.

Again somewhere else it does the same thing then i need to repeat the same.

My Operating System is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

I looked in the internet for solution. but strangely it seems like no one got this problem.

Can anyone please provide me a solution for this?

Comment: Add the batch file code please.

Comment: check if there is a `PAUSE` in your code.

Comment: there is post on serverfault that may help :
http://serverfault.com/questions/314194/why-does-windows-command-prompt-stalls-until-a-key-is-pressed-when-executing-lon

Comment: Thanks Kayasax. That was the problem. Now my bat files are running fine